# Getting node name when using search file attachments module

Tags: 7, search

I am using search file attachments module for searching attached file's content. When two nodes have the same attachment I had a problem that it is showing only attached file names, not nodes.

I want to display which file attached to which node also.

Any help on how to achieve this?

Comment: Hello. You was able to get one file attached to 2 nodes? Or 2 separate files that just happens to be identical?

Comment: Two seperate files attached to two seperate nodes, but the file is same, for example test.pdf

Comment: Need this in d8.